# ChangeNotifierProxyProvider to act as a Selector rather than Consumer

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

At the moment I have a `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` which pulls one value from a normal `ChangeNotifierProvider`. At the moment, when anything changes in the ChangeNotifierProvider, my ChangeNotifierProxyProvider will be notified and cause a number of other rebuilds from UI's who depend on the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider. Is there a way to only have the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider notified when only a single variable from the ChangeNotifierProvider changes?

```
  MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MainProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<MainProvider, GuideProvider>(
          create: (_) => GuideProvider(),
          update: (_, mainProvider, guideProvider) {
            return guideProvider
              ..activeState = mainProvider.activeState
              ..heading = mainProvider.activeState.stateName;
          },
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<MainProvider, ExploreProvider>(
          create: (_) => ExploreProvider(),
          update: (_, mainProvider, exploreProvider) {
            return exploreProvider..activeState = mainProvider.activeState;
          },
        )
      ],
      //update method and other code
  );
```

So in the case above I only want the Explore and Guide providers to update when the variable `activeState` changes in the `MainProvider`.